# React, what is c in filters function

Tags: javascript

I have the following code from a tutorial

```
 handleDelete = counterId => {
    const counters = this.state.counters.filter(c => c.id !== counterId); 

    this.setState({ counters });
  };
```

I am creating a new constant which has the existing array with the counterId removed.

But I do not understand what "c" is doing, and where "c.id" comes from?

Why is it not "counterId", the property I have bound to the function.

Thanks

Comment: It's a new ES6 feature called Arrow function (look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). You can replace `c => c.id !== counterId` by `function(c) { return c.id !== counterId }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not React JS. It's JavaScript's [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). It denotes the current item in the counter. If the return value of the function is truthy, the element will be preserved. If not, it will be removed.

Example with the same code:

```js
const _counters = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Praveen"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "Kumar"
}];

const handleDelete = counterId => {
  const counters = _counters.filter(c => c.id !== counterId);
  return counters;
};

// Let's try deleting the Kumar.
console.log(handleDelete(2));
```

In the above code, I have used `_counters` for showing it a state variable. If you wanna see what's happening inside, look at the console:

```js
const _counters = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Praveen"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "Kumar"
}];

const handleDelete = counterId => {
  const counters = _counters.filter(c => {console.log(c);return c.id !== counterId});
  return counters;
};

// Let's try deleting the Kumar.
console.log(handleDelete(2));
```

Comment: ```c``` is the name that you are using for each item that exists in your array ```counters``` you can for example use another name like ```counterItem``` ```const counters = this.state.counters.filter(counterItem => counterItem.id !== counterId);```

Comment: Don't forget to talk about Arrow function, `c` (or `counterId`) is a param of `handleDelete` function

Answer (score 1):

Your question is regarding [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method which was introduced as part of the [ECMAScript 5.1 spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.20) - this method is not provided by the React framework - the programmer just happens to be using a native JavaScript method in their React code.

`Array.prototype.filter` accepts a callback function an argument:

> callbackfn should be a function that accepts three arguments and
>   returns a value that is coercible to the Boolean value true or false.
>   filter calls callbackfn once for each element in the array, in
>   ascending order, and constructs a new array of all the values for
>   which callbackfn returns true. callbackfn is called only for elements
>   of the array which actually exist; it is not called for missing
>   elements of the array.

The 3 arguments are provided to the callback function by the browser - [here are the argument details (as per MDN)](http://element%20The%20current%20element%20being%20processed%20in%20the%20array.%20indexOptional%20The%20index%20of%20the%20current%20element%20being%20processed%20in%20the%20array.%20arrayOptional%20The%20array%20filter%20was%20called%20upon.):

> **element** - *this would be `c` in the code example you provided*
>
> The current element being processed in the array.
>
> **index `Optional`**
>
> The index of the current element being processed in the array.
>
> **array `Optional`**
>
> The array filter was called upon.

Here is an example of how to implement `filter` in order to create a new array that contains all the elements of `counters` that don't have an `id` that matches `counterId`

```js
const counters = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}, {id: 5}];
const counterId = 3;

//Log the result of the filter method
console.log(counters.filter(c => c.id !== counterId));

//The exact same thing can be written using pre-ES6 function declaration, like so:
console.log(counters.filter(function(c) {
  return c.id !== counterId;
}));
```

Finally, don't let the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax confuse you either, it's exactly the same as using a function declaration (in this scenario) - I included both approaches in the code sample above.

Answer (score -1):

c iis the item iteration for each element in the array  it passes all element one by on and what you want to do in this element

```js
const arr=["firstelment","secandElemnt","theardElemt"];
 console.log(arr.map(itemInARRy=>`${itemInARRy}+waht you want to do theelment `))
```

ounter =[{itm1:{...},item2:{},item3:{..},...]
if dowing 
counter.filter(c=>)
that is al item  c=[item1,item2,item3,...]
it all elemnt that found in arry or object
if you not uderstand commit in describtion

Comment: This is incoherent - consider using punctuation, formatting, and proof-reading